# PHP Echoing in the wrong location in the page

Tags: php, html

Im trying to create a page that will display orders from a database. If it doesnt find any results it should be display "No results" or so. It does display it when there arent any. However, it displays on top of the headers instead of the body of the table where the results are displayed.

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <table class="table table-striped shadow bg-white table-hover mb-3">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th scope="col">Order Number</th>
                <th scope="col">Image</th>
                <th scope="col">Buyer Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Product Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Order Date</th>
                <th scope="col">Price</th>
                <th scope="col">Status</th>
                <th scope="col">Action</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              
            <?php
                $userid = $_SESSION['userid'];
                $sql = "
                select
                O.orderid as 'orderid', O.totalprice as 'totalprice', U.firstname as 'firstname', U.lastname as 'lastname', P.productname as 'productname', O.userid as 'userid', O.orderstatus as 'orderstatus', OS.status as 'status', OS.statusid as 'statusid', P.image as 'productPhoto'
                from
                orders O
                INNER JOIN
                users U ON
                O.userid = U.userid
                INNER JOIN
                orderstatus OS ON
                O.orderstatus = OS.statusid
                INNER JOIN
                products P ON
                P.productid = O.productid
                WHERE
                P.userid = $userid AND O.orderstatus = 3;
                ";

                $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
                

                if($resultCheck > 0 ){
                  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                    echo '
                      <tr>
                      <th scope="row">'.$row['orderid'].'</th>
                      <th scope="row">
                        <img src="images/'.$row['productPhoto'].'" class="img-fluid" alt="Product image" style="height:100px; width: 100px;">
                      </th>
                      <th scope="row">'.$row['firstname'].' '.$row['lastname']. '</th>

                      <!-- PRODUCT NAME -->
                      <th scope="row">'.$row['productname'].'</th>

                      <!-- ORDER DATE -->
                      <td>06/28/2020</td>

                      <form action="../inc/manageorders_actions.inc.php" METHOD="POST">
                        <input type="hidden" value=" '. $row['orderid'] .' " name="orderid">
                        
                        <!-- PRICE -->
                        <td>'.'PHP '.$row['totalprice'].'</td>

                        <!-- STATUS -->
                        <td>
                        
                        '. $row['status'] .'
                        
                        </td>

                        <!-- ACTION -->
                        <td class="px-5">
                          <div class="row my-1 w-75">
                           <input type="submit" value="To pack" name="topack">
                          </div>
                          <div class="row my-1 w-75">
                            <input type="submit" value="Packed" name="packed">
                          </div>
                          <div class="row my-1 w-75">
                            <input type="submit" value="In delivery" name="beingdelivered">
                          </div>
                          <div class="row my-1 w-75">
                           <input type="submit" value="Delivery" name="delivered">
                          </div>
                        </td>

                      </form>
                      </tr>
                    ';
                  }
                }else{
                  echo 'No results';
                }


            ?>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
```

[image]

Comment: You aren't wrapping that output in a `<tr><td colspan="8">  ... </td>`

Comment: Thanks! I understand now.

Answer (score 3):

You can't just echo *No results* inside `<tbody>`.

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <table class="table table-striped shadow bg-white table-hover mb-3">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th scope="col">Order Number</th>
                <th scope="col">Image</th>
                <th scope="col">Buyer Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Product Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Order Date</th>
                <th scope="col">Price</th>
                <th scope="col">Status</th>
                <th scope="col">Action</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              
            <?php
                $userid = $_SESSION['userid'];
                $sql = "
                select
                O.orderid as 'orderid', O.totalprice as 'totalprice', U.firstname as 'firstname', U.lastname as 'lastname', P.productname as 'productname', O.userid as 'userid', O.orderstatus as 'orderstatus', OS.status as 'status', OS.statusid as 'statusid', P.image as 'productPhoto'
                from
                orders O
                INNER JOIN
                users U ON
                O.userid = U.userid
                INNER JOIN
                orderstatus OS ON
                O.orderstatus = OS.statusid
                INNER JOIN
                products P ON
                P.productid = O.productid
                WHERE
                P.userid = $userid AND O.orderstatus = 3;
                ";

                $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
                

                if($resultCheck > 0 ){
                  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                    echo '
                      <tr>
                      <th scope="row">'.$row['orderid'].'</th>
                      <th scope="row">
                        <img src="images/'.$row['productPhoto'].'" class="img-fluid" alt="Product image" style="height:100px; width: 100px;">
                      </th>
                      <th scope="row">'.$row['firstname'].' '.$row['lastname']. '</th>

                      <!-- PRODUCT NAME -->
                      <th scope="row">'.$row['productname'].'</th>

                      <!-- ORDER DATE -->
                      <td>06/28/2020</td>

                      <form action="../inc/manageorders_actions.inc.php" METHOD="POST">
                        <input type="hidden" value=" '. $row['orderid'] .' " name="orderid">
                        
                        <!-- PRICE -->
                        <td>'.'PHP '.$row['totalprice'].'</td>

                        <!-- STATUS -->
                        <td>
                        
                        '. $row['status'] .'
                        
                        </td>

                        <!-- ACTION -->
                        <td class="px-5">
                          <div class="row my-1 w-75">
                           <input type="submit" value="To pack" name="topack">
                          </div>
                          <div class="row my-1 w-75">
                            <input type="submit" value="Packed" name="packed">
                          </div>
                          <div class="row my-1 w-75">
                            <input type="submit" value="In delivery" name="beingdelivered">
                          </div>
                          <div class="row my-1 w-75">
                           <input type="submit" value="Delivery" name="delivered">
                          </div>
                        </td>

                      </form>
                      </tr>
                    ';
                  }
                }else{
                  echo '<tr><td colspan="8">No results</td></tr>';
                }


            ?>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
```

The `<tbody>` element required `<tr>` and `<td>` before display the contents. See [document here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table).

Comment: Explain your answer

Comment: It's correct answer.

Comment: Vee explained it

Comment: @symcbean I was explained that can't just echo _No results_ inside `<tbody>`.

Comment: Yes - I was trying to tell gview you had already explained it and his/her comment was redundant.

Comment: @symcbean Oh. Sorry. :-)

Comment: Gave you an upvote.  ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are outputting it directly in the body tag. You need to at least wrap it inside `<tr><td>`

```
echo "<tr><td>No results</td></tr>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don’t echoing a  formatted row like the results of the query? An then putting “no results” instead of data in it…